# How to convert asmx service to rest to invoke with URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, rest

I have created asmx service, how do I invoke it via "URL"?

Here is my code:

```
[WebMethod]
public string start(string id, string name)
{
   string newname = name;
   return newname;
}
```

Here is my current URL:

```
url = "http://localhost:XXXXX/WebService.asmx/start?id=" +id+ "&name="+name;
```

Here is my "Web.config":

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
     </compilation>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1000000"/>
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
  <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
</system.web>
   <system.webServer>
     <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can decorate your method to allow HTTP GET requests

```
 [WebMethod]  
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]
    public string start(string id, string name)
    {
       string newname = name;
       return newname;
    }
```

and do the following in web.config file

```
<system.web>
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
  </protocols>
```

> Setting the UseHttpGet property to true might pose a security risk for
>   your application if you are working with sensitive data or
>   transactions. In GET requests, the message is encoded by the browser
>   into the URL and is therefore an easier target for tampering.
>
> Note that this method of performing GET requests does come with some
>   security risks. According to the [MSDN documentation for UseHttpGet:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.usehttpget.aspx)

Hope this helps

Comment: frebin, see my edit, I have gave URL, how do I call it using URL with parameters. Thanks

Comment: Add namespace System.Web.Script.Services to get the [ScriptMethod] Assembly:System.Web.Extensions.dll

Comment: frebin, how do I get its return value using code by calling URL.

Comment: frebin, using WPF and locally in web service

Comment: if you want to add the web service to the WPF application, the best and secure way is to add a web service reference to your project. i will recommend this approach.so that the service will automatically create proxy methods for you and you can simply use it like normal methods.

Comment: I want to just check its response by calling URL, in my Web Service Method. @Frebin

Comment: you can better refer the following link to know more http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/consuming-web-service-in-wpf-application/

Comment: frebin, how to call this URL from Java client, Note: using URL like this way: url = "http://localhost:XXXXX/WebService.asmx/start?id=" +id+ "&name="+name;    Java client wants to call this web service. Please tell me

Comment: that you can call like a normal ajax request. use jquery plugin to achieve this. refer the link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/529847/Calling-ASP-NET-WebService-from-jQuery

Comment: frebin, can you post the code please, how to do it?

Comment: this video from youtube shows everything you want https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TDOJJ0sd_bw

Comment: frebin, keep it up brother. love n hugs!!

Comment: I've a controller that get by post method an object from rest service. When i get this object i need to send to asmx web service. How can i do this?